# Swift Generics Error "Type '$T10' does not conform to protocol 'MyProtocol'" (beta 5)

Tags: generics, swift, protocols

I'm attempting to create a DataContext class with some generic methods for working with various data entities. One of the features I'd like to have is to be able to update related entities using navigation properties. Here's an example of what I have so far:

Context class:

```
class DataContext
{    
    private var contextItems: [ContextItem] = []

    ...

    func UpdateNavigationProperty<T: ContextEntity>(inout oldValue: T?, inout navigationId: Int?,  newValue: T?)
    {
        if let newValue = newValue {
            if dataContext.GetContextItem(newValue) == nil {
                dataContext.Add(newValue)
                if newValue.id > 0 {
                    if let item = dataContext.GetContextItem(newValue) {
                        item.state = .None
                    }
                    if navigationId != newValue.id {
                        navigationId = newValue.id
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        oldValue = newValue
    }
}
```

Protocol definition:

```
protocol ContextEntity : NSObjectProtocol
{
    var id: Int { get set }

    func Save()
    func Delete()
}
```

`Vehicle` class is a convenience base class for`class Car: Vehicle, ContextEntity`, etc.:

```
class Vehicle : NSObject
{
    var id: Int
    var driverId: Int

    private var _driver: Person?
    var driver: Person? {
        get {
            if(_driver == nil && driverId != 0) {
                _driver = dataContext.Get(driverId)
            }
            return _driver
        }
        set {
            dataContext.UpdateNavigationProperty(&_driver, navigationId: &driverId as Int?, newValue: newValue)
        }
    }

}
```

Related class:

```
class Person: NSObject, ContextEntity
{
    var id: Int
    //MARK: ContextEntity Implementation    
    func Save() { }
    func Delete() { }
}
```

The line `dataContext.UpdateNavigationProperty(&_driver, navigationId: &driverId as Int?, newValue: newValue)` throws the error:

> Type '$T10' does not conform to protocol 'ContextEntity'

For some reason that I have been unable to discover, the generic method is not understanding that the objects passed to the generic method do, in fact, conform to `ContextEntity` (see `Person` class definition)

Am I misunderstanding Swift generics entirely? Or is this some sort of bug?

**Edit**

Navigation properties on the `Person` class (not depicted in examples) do not have this error. So I'm assuming that the compiler is (mistakenly?) using the type of the calling class as the generic method's type in question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

This is neither a generics error, nor a protocol error, but is that the compiler is failing to tell me what the actual error is.

The error is in that I'm attempting to cast the in-out parameter `navigationId` from `Int` to `Int?`, which it doesn't appear to like. Nor does it like if I try to pass in an `Int` directly

The correct call on the setter would be to use an intermediary variable:

```
var navId: Int? = driverId
dataContext.UpdateNavigationProperty(&_driver, navigationId: &navId, newValue: newValue)
if navId != nil {
    driverId = navId!
}
```